# What are the => signs used for

Tags: php

Well, i get it that - to access an method of an object of a class we use `->` sign. But why is `=>` sign used for ? Like in the below code its used for index and value of array:

```
<?php
    $a=array();

    $a['Ground'] = 5.95;
    $a['2nd day'] = 6.8;
    $a['night'] = 7;

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
   $msg = $key . '=' . $value .'<br>';
   echo $msg;
 }
    ?>
```

But what does it mean and when to use it?

Comment: You can find the answer here: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=> sign is used to define array key value pair

```
$array = array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2");
```